# require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; ERROR

Tags: php, html, json, login, composer

Estoy trabajando con un login con inicio de sesion por google, pero me tira un error. Este es mi codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me tira, al ejecutar, el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo lo tengo (autoload),lo vi. Cual puede ser el error? Puede ser el composer lock?

Comment: Pero ¿tienes el archivo en el subdirectorio `vendor` (`C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor`) o en el mismo que tu `redirect.php`?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Ahora que lo dices, creo que no. En la misma carpeta donde tengo el redirect.php no,creo que ni siquiera en htdocs. Claro ,así nunca iba a funcionar, gracias! Lo voy a probar